# Visualise Nondeterministic Finite Automata in JAVA

Tags: java, swing

I will be building a program on how to construct a NFA , the output of this particular program is visualise out the NFA in a graphical user interface. The final output of the program must be something like this: [image: this]

My question is how do I get started on "drawing" the states in circle , adding edges , inserting the input between two states, how do I program the GUI part by using java? please help me out..

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Answer (score 0):

Ty to look to https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph. There is swing/web examples. Manual is here https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.